# How can I change the date on X-Axis when using ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image]
I want to adjust my date on X-axis to format like "%m/%d/%y". How can I change it correctly? Thank you!

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
```

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(1524528000, 1524614400, 1524700800, 
                                  1524787200, 1524873600, 1524960000, 1525046400, 1525132800, 1525219200, 
                                  1525305600, 1525392000, 1525478400, 1525564800, 1525651200, 1525737600, 
                                  1525824000, 1525910400, 1525996800, 1524528000, 1524873600, 1525910400
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), Condition = c("Simulated", 
                                                                 "Simulated", "Simulated", "Simulated", "Simulated", "Simulated", 
                                                                 "Simulated", "Simulated", "Simulated", "Simulated", "Simulated", 
                                                                 "Simulated", "Simulated", "Simulated", "Simulated", "Simulated", 
                                                                 "Simulated", "Simulated", "Measured", "Measured", "Measured"), 
LAI = c(2.44, 2.44, 2.44, 2.44, 2.44, 2.44, 2.44, 2.44, 2.44, 
        2.44, 2.44, 2.44, 2.44, 2.44, 2.44, 2.44, 2.44, 2.44, 2.56666666666667, 
        2.56666666666667, 2.7)), row.names = c(NA, -21L), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                    "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

code:

```
X0_40cm <- read_excel("C:/Users/Connie/Desktop/LAI/Wheat_2017-2018.xlsx")
plot1 <- ggplot(X0_40cm, aes(Date,LAI,group=1))+
  geom_point(data=subset(X0_40cm, Condition=="Measured"),col="blue")+
  geom_line(data=subset(X0_40cm, Condition=="Simulated"),col="black")+
  scale_x_date(labels=date_labels("%m/%d/%y"))+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,7.5)) +
  labs(title="Summer maize of I plot in 2018",y="LAI",x="Date")+
  theme_update(plot.title=element_text(hjust=0.5))
plot1
```

Comment: scales::date_format instead of date_labels?

Comment: It doesn't work:(

Comment: Is variable Date formatted as a Date? scales::date_format(format = "%m/%d/%Y")(as.Date("2019-01-20")) works, but scales::date_format(format = "%m/%d/%Y")("2019-01-20") gives an error.

Comment: `date_labels` not found. Can you please make this question reproducible?

Comment: `scale_x_date(labels = function(a) format(a, format="%m/%d/%Y"))` works for me (and my fake data). So does `scale_x_date(labels = scales::date_format("%m/%d/%Y"))`.

Comment: Without seeing your data, this might be chasing the wrong problem. I suspect that stefan's suggestion is quite possible, but it could be a number of other things, too. LIN KANG, many of our uncertainties are because we don't have a sample of your data. Can you provide the output from `dput(head(X0_40cm))` with the three-four columns needed for the plot.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for help! I have provided the dput data above.

Comment: you have to convert your Date column, e.g. X0_40cm <- dplyr::mutate(X0_40cm, Date = as.Date(Date)). Then scales::date_format works fine otherwise is raises an`Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only`

Comment: @stefan you were right in your second comment, nice job.

Comment: Thank you guys so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seemed to be a few issues which users rightly pointed out in the comments. First let's load packages and our data.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

X0_40cm <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(1524528000, 1524614400, 1524700800, 1524787200, 1524873600, 
                                       1524960000, 1525046400, 1525132800, 1525219200, 1525305600, 
                                       1525392000, 1525478400, 1525564800, 1525651200, 1525737600, 
                                       1525824000, 1525910400, 1525996800, 1524528000, 1524873600, 
                                       1525910400), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
                    Condition = c("Simulated", "Simulated", "Simulated", "Simulated", "Simulated", 
                                  "Simulated", "Simulated", "Simulated", "Simulated", "Simulated", 
                                  "Simulated", "Simulated", "Simulated", "Simulated", "Simulated", 
                                  "Simulated", "Simulated", "Simulated", "Measured", "Measured", "Measured"), 
                    LAI = c(2.44, 2.44, 2.44, 2.44, 2.44, 2.44, 2.44, 2.44, 2.44, 
                            2.44, 2.44, 2.44, 2.44, 2.44, 2.44, 2.44, 2.44, 2.44, 
                            2.56666666666667, 2.56666666666667, 2.7)), 
               row.names = c(NA, -21L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

As @stefan pointed out in his comment, you will need to convert the column `Date` in your data to type *date* because right now it is of type date-time.

```
head(X0_40cm)
# # A tibble: 6 x 3
#   Date                Condition   LAI
#   <dttm>              <chr>     <dbl>
# 1 2018-04-24 00:00:00 Simulated  2.44
# 2 2018-04-25 00:00:00 Simulated  2.44
# 3 2018-04-26 00:00:00 Simulated  2.44
# 4 2018-04-27 00:00:00 Simulated  2.44
# 5 2018-04-28 00:00:00 Simulated  2.44
# 6 2018-04-29 00:00:00 Simulated  2.44
```

If you don't convert the field beforehand you will get the following error:

> Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only

You can convert `Date` as follows:

```
X0_40cm <- X0_40cm %>% 
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date))
```

Before you can plot as desired, you need to address the function `date_labels()` which you originally used in `scale_x_date()`. Instead, as @r2evans provided two valid options in the comments, such as `scale_x_date(labels = scales::date_format("%m/%d/%Y"))` which I'll used below:

```
ggplot(data = X0_40cm, aes(as_date(Date),LAI,group=1))+
  geom_point(data=subset(X0_40cm, Condition=="Measured"),col="blue")+
  geom_line(data=subset(X0_40cm, Condition=="Simulated"),col="black")+
  scale_x_date(labels=date_format("%m/%d/%y"))+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,7.5)) +
  labs(title="Summer maize of I plot in 2018",y="LAI",x="Date")+
  theme_update(plot.title=element_text(hjust=0.5))
```

[image]